# Using jQuery Validator like facebook;

Tags: jquery, facebook, validation

How can I use jQuery validator like facebook signup page? Only one box for the results of error?

Thanks,

Lincoln

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery validation plugin:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

Here's an example:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation#Example

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer..

It's Sign up page, not sign in, my mistake, sorry.

http://img813.imageshack.us/img813/4903/53140416.png

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**You mean this:**

[image]

Well facebook dosen't use jQuery for this. Instead the `php` script on their server validated the username Password and injects its HTML.

You dont even need jquery for this unless you are validating Username Password from an Ajax Call.

That said filling a div woth Error message is quite straight Formward:

```
$("#divID").html = "We have an Error";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer..

It's Sign up page, not sign in, my mistake, sorry.
I'm using this plugin, but how can I do that: 
http://img813.imageshack.us/img813/4903/53140416.png

Thanks

Comment: There also you can have a div with all that formatting via CSS and then bind a jquery code  to page lookhere for various validating options  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

Answer (score 0):

Yes stated above by the others, the jQuery validation plugin can do what you are asking for:

General information on the validation plugin:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Different options using the validation plugin:
docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

Read up on how the validation plugin works. It's very simple. And when you ready to implement the error messaging, read about "errorPlacement" in the validation options page linked above. That is one way to go about implementing your form validation and messaging.

Comment: ok, thanks for your response.
but, if I do that, multiple errors appear in this box, I want one error at time...you know how to do that?
Lincoln